# Scala how to match two dfs if mathes then update the key in first df

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in two dataframes:

selectedPersonDF:

```
ID    key
1     
2     
3
4
5
```

selectedDetailsDF:

```
first  second third  key
--------------------------
1       9       9    777
9       8       8    878
8       10      10   765
10      12      19   909
11      2       20   708
```

Code :

```
val personDF = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "false").csv("person.csv")
val detailsDF = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "false").csv("details.csv")

val selectedPersonDF=personDF.select((col("ID"),col("key"))).show() 
val selectedDetailsDF=detailsDF.select(col("first"),col("second"),col("third"),col("key")).show()
```

I have to match the selectedPersonDF id column with selectedDetailsDF all the columns(First, Second, Third) if any of the column data matches with persons id then we have to take the key value from selectedDetailsDF and have to update in selectedPersonDF key column.

Expected output (in selectedPersonDF):

```
ID    key
1     777
2     708     
3
4
5
```

and after removing the first row from persons'df since its matched with detailsdf remaining data should be stored in another df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` and use `||` *condition checking* and `left join` as

```
val finalDF = selectedPersonDF.join(selectedDetailsDF.withColumnRenamed("key", "key2"), $"ID" === $"first" || $"ID" === $"second" || $"ID" === $"third", "left")
  .select($"ID", $"key2".as("key"))
  .show(false)
```

so `finalDF` should give you

```
+---+----+
|ID |key |
+---+----+
|1  |777 |
|2  |708 |
|3  |null|
|4  |null|
|5  |null|
+---+----+
```

We can call `.na.fill("")` on above *dataframe* (`key` column has to be `StringType()`) to get

```
+---+---+
|ID |key|
+---+---+
|1  |777|
|2  |708|
|3  |   |
|4  |   |
|5  |   |
+---+---+
```

After that you can use `filter` to separate the *dataframe* into *matching* and *non matching* using `key` column with *value* and *null* repectively

```
val notMatchingDF = finalDF.filter($"key" === "")
val matchingDF = finalDF.except(notMatchingDF)
```

**Updated for if the column names of selectedDetailsDF is unknown except the key column**

If the *column names* of the *second dataframe* is **unknown** then you will have to form an `array` column of the unknown columns as

```
val columnsToCheck = selectedDetailsDF.columns.toSet - "key" toList

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tempSelectedDetailsDF = selectedDetailsDF.select(array(columnsToCheck.map(col): _*).as("array"), col("key").as("key2"))
```

Now `tempSelectedDetailsDF` dataframe has two columns: combined column of all the unknown columns as an `array` column and the key column renamed as `key2`.

After that you would need a `udf` function for checking the condition while joining

```
val arrayContains = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], value: String) => array.contains(value))
```

And then you `join` the dataframes using the call to the defined `udf` function as

```
val finalDF = selectedPersonDF.join(tempSelectedDetailsDF, arrayContains($"array", $"ID"), "left")
  .select($"ID", $"key2".as("key"))
  .na.fill("")
```

Rest of the process is already defined above.

I hope the answer is helpful and understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my requirement i cant give column name directly i have to do match condition with selectedPersonDF and selectedDetailsDF if mathes we have to take the key and update

Comment: so you are saying is that `first second third` column names are not known. Is that right?

Comment: is the name of the `key` column known? I guess it has to be known.

Comment: @RavikumarReddyYeruva, I have updated the answer and hope it answers all the query you had :)

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance :) you can upvote too I guess ;)

Comment: From selectedPersonDF in current example i have only two columns hence i can use this in finalDF 'select($"ID", $"key2".as("key"))',, if suppose more columns is there then how can i select all the columns. it will be a tedious process to add all the columns in select.

Comment: You can always select an array of columns as I have done in the answer . by doing something like `columnsToCheck.map(col): _*`.

Comment: I am still facing little challenges when matching with multiple to multiple columns. Can you help me.

Comment: kindly help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098938/how-to-match-the-data-from-two-data-frames

Comment: that question is not clear to understand. And its already on hold

Comment: Here in selectedPersonDF: i have  two columns "ID    key" and i am getting the output. in real time scenario i will have to show more columns in the output. i am not able to select all the columns. if selectedPersonDF contains (ID Key X Y Z) then i have to display all the columns in my output.

Comment: what do you mean by `i am not able to select all the columns` ? can you clarify? A separate question would be good for the explanation. so that you get different answers including mine.